# Getting lines from char[] in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, console, char

I'm coding in C# for a little console program that should pick some lines in a text file and put them after a little description. The code "imports" file content into a char array and I'd like to split the array into lines. This program also write these files.

```
public static char[] complete = File.ReadAllText(workFile.ToCharArray();
//here there should be something that brings me line1
//do anything else
Console.WriteLine("Line 1 is: " + line1);
```

How can I do it? Thanks for every answer!

Comment: You need an array of string from file and not an array of char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're looking for [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] complete = File.ReadAllLines(workFile);
Console.WriteLine("Line 1 is: {0}", complete[0]);
```

Comment: @EnricoZaghini yw :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var complete = File.ReadAllText(workFile).ToCharArray();

var count = complete.Count(c => c == '\n');
if (count > 0)
{
    count += 1;
}
```

Above code snippet count all newline characters. Reason I'm adding +1 is technically once you find EOL character at end of line, it cause start of another line.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying it, but I'm going to use the answer above for my slim application.